# Auto-insert hyperlinks in Hotmail in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, hotmail

I am trying to get my mom to use Google Chrome. However she gets upset because in Hotmail with Google Chrome, links pasted into the email body show up as plain text, while Internet Explorer turns them into a hyperlink automatically.

Is there an extension or some trick to automatically turn pasted `http://` links into hyperlinks in Chrome?

Comment: Does it not convert them on send?

Comment: Yes, it does not. If you add a link and then send an email it remains in plain text in the recipient's email client.

Comment: What version of chrome are you using? Apparently, something in the updated version of chrome blocks hyperlinks. Have a look at http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=0915f71b7b667f57&hl=en. Downgrading from Chrome v1.0.154.48 to v1.0.154.36 in this case seemed to fix the problem. Slothishtype.